# Call Vuex Action via Vue Computed Setter

Tags: vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, vuex

I have a value for a counter stored in Firebase.

```
{
  name: 'sheep',
  total: 0
}
```

I sync that to a value in Vuex state using an action calling Firebase.

```
loadedCounter ({ commit }) {
  commit('setLoading', true)
  firebase.database().ref('animals').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    let counter = []
    let obj = snapshot.val()
    for (let key in obj) {
      counter.push({
        name: obj[key].name,
        total: obj[key].total
      })
    }
    commit('setLoadedCounter', test)
    commit('setLoading', false)
  })
},
```

I then use a `computed` property in my Vue component to get the value. The getter is working.

```
computed: {
sheepCounter: {
  get () {
    let test = this.$store.getters.getSheep
    return test.total
  },
  set (value) {
    this.$store.commit('updateSheep', value)
  }
}
```

The setter however errors out. I get this error in the console:

> [vuex] unknown mutation type: updateSheep

I believe the issue is that the set can only reference a mutation and `updateSheep` is an `action`. But from my understanding it has to be an action because it's asynchronous code.

```
updateSheep ({commit}, payload) {
  firebase.database().ref('animals').child('sheep').update({total: payload})
},
```

How can I set the data using the computer property set that sync to firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by dispatching the action. I was trying to commit an action. Dispatching is for Actions:

```
this.$store.dispatch('updateSheep', value)
```

not

```
this.$store.commit('updateSheep', value)
```